# Good tool for making MySQL queries graphically?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

After working a while with Access 2010 I have fell in love with the way you make queries. You just pick the tables you want in your SELECT query, then you get all the JOINs laid out automatically, and you can just pick and choose what you want.

However, I cannot find any good similar tools for MySQL. I tried MySQL Workbench once, but it wasn't very easy to use compared to Access. I'm seriously considering making a parallel Access database to construct the JOINs, even though it requires me to do structural changes both in Access and phpMyAdmin, and to make dummy data in Access, and to convert the SQL to MySQL-friendly code..

Are there any GOOD tools out there to help me do this instead of my Access/MySQL in parallel approach?

Comment: If you end up not finding something you like then instead of duplicating your solution you'd be better off just learning the SQL syntax to write your own joins.  It would be far beneficial in the long run.  The skills are more widely applicable.

Comment: @squillman No, they aren't difficult. The reason why I prefer it is because when I have two tables with 5 tables in between (graphically), it takes a lot of time to write the joins... And you have to print out a graphical representation, or draw one, so you can "find your way" when you are doing joins. Because remembering the way when you have 30 tables isn't easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Visio. Here's a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409355/generate-visio-erd-from-existing-mysql-database).

Here's a [how-to](http://sajjadhossain.com/2009/02/12/reverse-engineering-mysql-database-with-microsoft-visio/) about making the connection.